# Closed function and adherence

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have by definition that a function is cloded if the image of a closed set by this function still closed

And i want to prove that $$f:E\rightarrow F ~\text{is closed} \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(\overline{B})\subset\overline{f^{-1}(B)}, \forall B \subset F$$

where $(E,\tau)$ and $(F,\theta)$ are topological spaces

How to do please

Comment: is $f$ assumed to be onto?

Comment: NO just closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is false as stated: let $X = [0,1]$, $Y = \mathbb{R}$ (both in the usual topology), $\forall x: f(x) = 0$. This $f$ is closed and continuous, and letting $B = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, we see that $f^{-1}[\overline{B}] = [0,1]$ and $\emptyset = f^{-1}[B] = \overline{f^{-1}[B]}$.

Comment: but why you have $f^{-1}(B)=\overline{f^{-1}(B)}$ ?

Comment: The empty set is its own closure